# Measurable functions :

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f$ be a measurable function in $(X,\mathcal C,µ)$ measure space. Show "$1+f$" function is measurable too, by using the definition of measurable func.?

How do you prove 1+f is measurable, just using the definition or theorem?

Comment: Find the definition of a measurability for functions and apply it to $1+f$.

Comment: If you have trouble with Henrik's method: write the definition of "measurable function" in your question, and show how you would try to apply it to $1+f$.  Then we can help you find your difficulty.

Comment: See the proof of the sum of measurable functions is measurable, and try to replicate it.

Comment: If this is the def. of measurable : A function f:X->R is measurable if, for every real number a, the set

 {x in X:f(x)>a} 
is measurable. When X=R with Lebesgue measure, or more generally any Borel measure, then all continuous functions are measurable. In fact, practically any function that can be described is measurable. Measurable functions are closed under addition and multiplication, but not composition.   HOW can i apply 1+f into this def. ? @GEdgar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your definition.

Assume $f : X \to \mathbb R$ is measurable.  That is: for every $a \in \mathbb R$,
$$
\{x \in X\;:\;f(x) > a\} \in \mathcal C .
\tag{$*$}
$$
I claim that $1+f$ is measurable.  [Function $1+f$ is the function that maps $x$ to $1+f(x)$.]  Let $b$ be any real number.  I must show that
$$
\{x \in X\;:\;1+f(x) > b\} \in \mathcal C .
$$
Now notice that $1+f(x) > b$ if and only if $f(x) > b-1$.  So
$$
\{x \in X\;:\;1+f(x) > b\} = \{x \in X\;:\;f(x) > b-1\} .
$$
Apply ($*$) with $a=b-1$ to get
$$
\{x \in X\;:\;1+f(x) > b\} \in \mathcal C ,
$$
as claimed.  Since this is true for every $b$, we conclude that $1+f$ is measurable.  [Another thing we used: if $b \in \mathbb R$, then $b-1 \in \mathbb R$.]

Comment: thanks, it helps me a lot.

Comment: what is the _C_ stands for?

Comment: sorry last quesiton was my mistake. I put the main question wrong. Measue space will be (X,_S_,µ) instead of (X,_C_,µ). Then i suppose {x ∈ X : f(x)>a}∈ _C_ will be changed with {x ∈ X : f(x)>a}∈ _S_. Is that right?